# How to cancel a download on Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, download-manager

I (accidentally) started downloading a 350 MB file from Google Chrome and I can't find the option to stop it, the downloads app just shows the files that have already finished but not the downloads in progress. The notification on my top bar just opens the downloads app.

Comment: Open downloads, click the box beside the file that's downloading, click the trash can icon.

Comment: There isn't any box beside any download. I'll upload a screencap when I get to my computer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just reproduced the steps needed to do this, last two steps may be the interesting ones:

- Open Google Chrome (v39)
- Start a large download (http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip)
- Wait a moment (it took some seconds for a notification to appear)
- Pull down the notification bar and click on the download entry
- You are taken to the download manager
- **Long click** on the corresponding entry
- Choose the **trash bin** from the **top action bar**

In case this does not work for you: Please edit your answer with your exact device model, Chrome and Android version number.
If you are doing a lot of downloads on your Android device consider installing a download manager like share downloader. It also supports pause and resume.

Comment: This is not working in my 4.4.2. When I click on the download entry, nothing happens.

Answer (score 5):

Go to App Drawer → Downloads → Find the downloading item, Delete that.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the best way is to turn off Wi-Fi and data (3g, 4g) and let the download fail.

Comment: When connected again, download started ,help.

Answer (score 1):

Long press the download app and then drag it to app info which should appear on the top of your home screen. Tap on force stop and its done!

Comment: Doesn't that leave the unfinished download somewhere?

Comment: No, download started when I open app again : ( ,help,I accidentally clicked 1.2 GB file and my wifi speed is low.

Comment: @fawad try long pressing the notification and then force stop?

Comment: Force stop stops downloading until I open app again. When I open chrome, download starts.