# How to cancel file download on Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, downloading, xiaomi

I accidentally clicked the download button of a 1.2 GB (my WiFi speed is slow so it's a problem) file from the Chrome browser on Android 4.4.4 KitKat. Now I want to cancel this download package, but it seems impossible to me.

I googled and found [this similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/82339/how-to-cancel-a-download-on-android-4-4-kitkat) but none of those answers helped me.

- My device download manager doesn't show Chrome's current downloading.
- When I close my WiFi, the download pause, but when I turn on WiFi, then the download resumes.
- When I force-stop the Chrome app, the download stops, but when I open it again, the download starts again.

My device is Xiaomi Mi Pad 1 (China version) running on MIUI. My device is not rooted.

Answer (score 1):

You can press on the file name which is downloading. After clicking it, you will get 2 options below that file: Cancel or Pause. Click on Cancel.

Comment: If you used xiaomi device,then you may know long pressing on notification will only opens notification settings of that app(chrome).

Comment: You can download an app called download manager https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tt.android.dm.view

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings - Apps - Download, and force stop the Download application and clear data.

Comment: It will delete my accounts passwords which were saved :/ that's only thing stopping me to do so.

Comment: @Fawad The download manager does not store any passwords.

Comment: OK,I force stopped both downloads and download manager,but it seems that chrome is downloading files. (Chrome app shows downloading notification). @MatthewRead